# How is this given distribution specified? What is the PDF?

Tags: distributions, notation

If you say that

$$
Y \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2(n-1) / (n-1)
$$

what does that mean then? Is it just a scaled version of the expression of the pdf?

Comment: This expression doesn't represent a PDF at all: it's attempting to describe the *distribution* of the random variable $Y.$  Expressions like this can even be used for distributions that have no PDF.  Although this notation is informal -- I avoid it due to the potential ambiguity -- I imagine you could safely interpret the "$\chi^2(n-1)$" term as referring to some (unnamed) random variable that has a $\chi^2(n-1)$ distribution and "$\sim$" would then mean "has the same distribution as."

Comment: Yes. I would interpret it as $\chi^2(n-1)$ means chi-square distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom. So, if X has that chi-squared distribution, then the distribution function for $Y$ is the same as the distribution of $\sigma^2 X/(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> This expression doesn't represent a PDF at all: it's attempting to
> describe the *distribution* of the random variable $Y.$  Expressions
> like this can even be used for distributions that have no PDF.
> Although this notation is informal -- I avoid it due to the potential
> ambiguity -- I imagine you could safely interpret the "$\chi^2(n-1)$"
> term as referring to some (unnamed) random variable that has a
> $\chi^2(n-1)$ distribution and "$\sim$" would then mean "has the same
> distribution as."

- whuber

> Yes. I would interpret it as $\chi^2(n-1)$ means chi-square
> distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom. So, if X has that
> chi-squared distribution, then the distribution function for $Y$ is
> the same as the distribution of $\sigma^2 X/(n-1)$.

- John L